# How to display label in center of symbol when using Points Displacement in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, overlapping-features

I have been attempting to display all the locations of some facilities I have to map. Due to the lat/long coordinates, they are overlapping. Therefore, I tried using points displacement when choosing my symbology. However, I could not get the labels for the points to be centered on the symbols. Is there a way to do this? Additionally, how can I prioritize which symbols/labels are displayed?

Comment: Providing sample data could help